# Days of Week Conditionals not working

Tags: function, label, conditional-statements, dayofweek

I am trying to obtain a due date based from the date and time of the system. Obtaining the due date is straight forward, but getting the label to change is just not working. The result I get is usually today's date.

```
Public Function FindDueDate()

    Dim Due As Date = Now

    If DayOfWeek.Monday Then
        DueDate.Text = Due.AddDays(14).ToString
    ElseIf DayOfWeek.Tuesday Then
        DueDate.Text = Due.AddDays(13).ToString
    ElseIf DayOfWeek.Wednesday And Hour(Now) < 16 Then
        DueDate.Text = Due.AddDays(12).ToString
    ElseIf DayOfWeek.Wednesday And Hour(Now) >= 16 Then
        DueDate.Text = Due.AddDays(19).ToString
    ElseIf DayOfWeek.Thursday Then
        DueDate.Text = Due.AddDays(18).ToString
    ElseIf DayOfWeek.Friday Then
        DueDate.Text = Due.AddDays(17).ToString
    ElseIf DayOfWeek.Saturday Then
        DueDate.Text = Due.AddDays(16).ToString
    ElseIf DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
        DueDate.Text = Due.AddDays(15).ToString
    End If

End Function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is:

```
Public Function FindDueDate()
    Dim Due As Date = Now

    If Due.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday Then
        DueDate.Text = Due.AddDays(14).ToString
    ElseIf Due.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Tuesday Then

    ...

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Nope, still getting today's date when I call the function, changing the date on my laptop confirms the label only changes to the current date.

Comment: What do you expect? The only date in your code is the one you specifically set to `Now`.

Comment: I want to add X amount of days to today's date depending on what day of the week it is.